# Structuring a Query or set of Queries

Tags: php, mysql, date, data-structures

I've had a busy day, so I might not be grasping the answer myself.
So, apologies if the answer is sitting right in front of me.

Basically I am trying to form a query page of data sorted by date in the following structure:

[image]

What I am having a hard time with is to determine how to query it.

```
query = SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC; {
echo Month

query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE month = Month ORDER BY date ASC; {

    }

}
```

Is the above structure the most efficient away to return the desired results in the image provided?
I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: No, it is not efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you suggest a more efficient way? I'm not asking for coding, just the an understanding of the logic behind it.

Comment: It's hard to advise without seeing the rest of your data structure, but a `GROUP BY` may help here - [try this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=group+by+month+mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get complicated. Things are this simple.

To group result by months:

```
GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
```

To group result by date:

```
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

-where `date` is the date column name.

Just palce it properly inside loops to get your problem solved.

Comment: This was what I was thinking, but won't the OP need to use aggregate functions in the `SELECT` columns to use this approach?

Comment: Use the logic, process the result properly.

Comment: that's great general advice, but can you expand on that in the context of the question? I wonder if it's easier to have an n+1 arrangement here anyway: one query selecting the months in use, and then a query for each block listing the data.

Comment: Use Subquries with JOIN..the rest you take care. I'm not here to spoon feed you.

Comment: OK, great! Feel free to edit that into your answer. I should make it clear that I'm not the OP - I am encouraging you to expand on your answer, which I thought was rather brief.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have gotten my code to work partially, it's displaying the results grouped by month, but will only return 1 result, even if there is 2 or more in the month..

"SELECT trips.*, months.month
FROM trips
JOIN months
ON months.month=monthname(trips.start_date) WHERE trips.tid = '$tid' GROUP BY monthname(trips.start_date) ORDER BY trips.start_date"

Answer (score 1):

once you get all records order by date using:

```
query = SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC;
```

you can echo first record month name and display record until month is not changed, when month is changed display month name again continue.

This should work as long as records are sorted and you won't need second query (which will in turn improve performance)